# вызов обработчика событий из одного компонента в другом компоненте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции, jsx

есть компонент

```
function App() {
  const handleClick= () => {
    const popupOpen = document.querySelector('.popup');
    popupOpen.classList.add('popup_open')
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="page">
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
      </div>
   </>
)}
```

в компоненте Main

```
function Main() {
  return (
    <main className="content">
      <section className="main">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="button"
            onClick={handleClick}
          ></button>
    </main>
  )
};
```

Я перенес обработчик событий из компонента Main в компонент App. При этом, я хочу чтобы он продолжал вызываться из компонента Main.

нужна Ваша помощь как это реализовать, передав ее в Main с помощью нового пропса например onEdit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. В компоненте Арр, пробросьте её компоненту Main `<Main handleClick = {handleClick}/>`
2. Получите функцию в компоненте Main из пропсов и вызывайте её при нажатии на кнопку `onClick={() => props.handleClick()}`

Получить доступ к пропсам в Main можно так `Main(props)`

Но работать напрямую с дом элементами используя реакт, не всегда хорошая идея. Это я про саму функцию  handleClick

Comment: Супер спасибо ),